# Flutterwave command not working (Flutterwave CLI)

Tags: flutterwave

When you run the command
`flutterwave -v` and it says command not found, you can fix it with the below hack.

---

**MAC**

in your terminal run

`export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

`source ~/.bashrc`

`echo 'source ~/.bashrc' >> ~/.bash_profile`

To verify that:

`echo $PATH`

(Restart the terminal, Check & Confirm the path is there)

Run the flutterwave command!

---

**WINDOWS**

So instead of `~/.composer/vendor/bin`, on Windows the following path should be used:

`C:\Users\<COMPUTER NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

Then update the PATH environment variable via e.g. command prompt with admin privileges:

`setx /M path "%path%;%appdata%\Composer\vendor\bin"`

`%appdata%` is added, so you don’t have to worry about adding your computer name.

---

**UBUNTU (Ubuntu 16 and above)**

`export PATH="~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some tips for some of the issues you may run into during the CLI setup:

1. ***Composer/Packagist could not find package for minimum stability*** after trying to run `composer global require flutterwavedev/cli` :- to resolve this run `composer global require flutterwavedev/cli:dev-master` instead.
2. ***No such file or directory*** after running `source ~/.bashrc` :- to resolve this run `touch ~/.bashrc` to create the file and `nano ~/.bashrc` to add the export path to the file.